# OpenLayers GetFeatureInfo Error in Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I was advised in a previous post to ask this question again using a small data sample

My base layer is a postgis vector dataset in WGS84

When I click on the map I get the following an error in the nodelist could somebody help
part of the error is here

```
        X and Y incorrectly specified Details:
        org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: X and Y incorrectly specified at org.geoserver.wms.featureinfo.GetFeatureInfoKvpReader.read(GetFeatureInf
        oKvpReader.java:162) at
        org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1230) at
        org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:488) at
        org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:231)
        at
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(Abs
        tractController.java:153) ava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My openlayers code is generated from a perl script the code below is the result of right click View Page Source.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/scale/scalebar-fat.css"/>
        <!-- Basic CSS definitions -->
        <style type="text/css">
            /* General settings */
            body {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: small;
            }
            /* Toolbar styles */
            #toolbar {
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
                display: none;
            }

            #toolbar ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #toolbar ul li {
                float: left;
                padding-right: 1em;
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
            }

            #toolbar ul li a {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: smaller;
                vertical-align: middle;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #toolbar ul li a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            #toolbar ul li * {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            /* The map and the location bar */
            #map {
                clear: both;
                position: relative;
                width: 600px;
                height: 600px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #wrapper {
                width: 512px;
            }

            #location {
                float: right;
            }

            #options {
                position: absolute;
                left: 13px;
                top: 7px;
                z-index: 3000;
            }

            /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
            table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-size: 90%;
                padding: .2em .1em;
            }

            table.featureInfo th {
                padding: .2em .2em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #eee;
            }

            table.featureInfo td {
                background: #fff;
            }

            table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
                background: #eee;
            }

            table.featureInfo caption {
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 100%;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: .2em .2em;
            }
     </style>

        </style>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/OpenLayers-2.11/OpenLayers.js"> </script>

    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/scale/ScaleBar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pureCoverage = false;
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
            // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
            OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;

        var map, scalebar;
        function createGeodesicPolygon(origin, radius, sides, rotation, projection) {

          if (projection.getCode() !== "EPSG:4326") {
          origin.transform(projection, new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
          }
          var latlon = new OpenLayers.LonLat(origin.x, origin.y);

          var angle;
          var new_lonlat, geom_point;
          var points = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
          angle = (i * 360 / sides) + rotation;
          new_lonlat = OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty(latlon, angle, radius);
          new_lonlat.transform(newOpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), projection);
          geom_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(new_lonlat.lon,new_lonlat.lat);
          points.push(geom_point);
          }
          var ring = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
          return new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([ring]);
          }

          var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
          div: "map",
          center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
          minResolution: "auto",
          maxResolution: "auto"
          });

        function init(){
        format = 'image/png';
         if(pureCoverage) {
            document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
            format = "image/jpeg";
        }

            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    1, 53, 3, 54
                );
                var options = {
                    controls: [],
                    //'PanZoomBar', 'Navigation', 'Scale', 'MousePosition'
                    maxExtent: bounds,
                    maxResolution: 0.00365234375,
                    projection: "EPSG:4326",
                    units: 'degrees'
                };
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

                //

            var Base = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Land",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {LAYERS: 'cite:land',
                 format: 'image/png',
                 isBaseLayer: true,
                 srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
                }
            );
            map.addLayers([Base]);

            var L1234 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "1234",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:10654',
                LAYERS: 'cite:Q_Results',
                transparent: 'true',
                isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );


            var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("myPolygonLayer",{
                styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                fillColor: "#33CC00",
                strokeColor: "#000000",
                strokeWidth: 1

                })
            }
            );

            var format = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT({
            'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
            'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            });

            var polygonFeature= format.read("POLYGON((1.9 53.17,2.4 53.17,2.4 53.49, 1.9 53.49,1.9 53.17))");

            vectorLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);

            map.addLayers([L1234,vectorLayer]);
            // build up all controls


                // build up all controls
              map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
                    position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
                }));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')));

                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({element: $('location')}));
                map.addControl(new openLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')}));


               var scalebar = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleBar({
                div: document.getElementById("scalebar"),
                displaySystem: "metric",
                minWidth: 175,
                maxWidth: 575,
                divisions: 4,
                subdivisions: 1,
                showMinorMeasures: true,
                abbreviateLabel: true,
                singleLine: true
            });
            map.addControl(scalebar);

            map.zoomToExtent(
                new OpenLayers.Bounds(1, 53, 3, 54)
            );

                // support GetFeatureInfo
                map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
                    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
                    var params = {
                        REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                        EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                        BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                        SERVICE: "WMS",
                        INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                        QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0].params.LAYERS,
                        FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                        Viewparams: 'kathy:10654',
                        Layers: 'cite:land,cite:Q_Results',
                        WIDTH: map.size.w,
                        HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                        format: format,
                        styles: map.layers[0].params.STYLES,
                        srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};

                    // handle the wms 1.3 vs wms 1.1 madness
                    if(map.layers[0].params.VERSION == "1.3.0") {
                        params.version = "1.3.0";
                        params.j = e.xy.x;
                        params.i = e.xy.y;
                    } else {
                        params.version = "1.1.1";
                        params.x = e.xy.x;
                        params.y = e.xy.y;
                    }

                    // merge filters
                    if(map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER != null) {
                        params.cql_filter = map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER;
                    }
                    if(map.layers[0].params.FILTER != null) {
                        params.filter = map.layers[0].params.FILTER;
                    }
                    if(map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID) {
                        params.featureid = map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID;
                    }
                    OpenLayers.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
                });

        }
        // end init
                // sets the HTML provided into the nodelist element
        function setHTML(response){
            document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = response.responseText;
        };


    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()">
    <h3>OpenLayers PostGis Layers</h3>
    <DIV id=layerswitcher class=olControlLayerSwitcher></DIV>
    <div id="map"></div>

        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="location">location</div>
        <div id="scale">        </div>
        <div id=scalebar></div>
    </div>
    <div id="nodelist">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Update New Error**

The above works if suggestions by iant are used however if an additional layer is added and the veiwparams in the GetFeatureInfo are altered to incorporate this new layer an error similar to 3 layers selected but 2 veiwparams occurs when you click on the map.

Please advise

```
            var L5678= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "5678",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:5678',
                LAYERS: 'cite:Q_Results',
                transparent: 'true',
                isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );

Viewparams: 'kathy:10654,5678',
```

Comment: OOpps Sorry I thought i Had i'll do so now

Comment: Wow! 100% acceptance, very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in firebug to see what the actual request that is sent looks like - my suspicion is that your x and y (or i an j) are being sent as reals not integers.

If so a quick fix would be to change:

```
params.x = e.xy.x;
params.y = e.xy.y;
```

to

```
params.x = Math.floor(e.xy.x);
params.y = Math.floor(e.xy.y);
```

Comment: Looked in firebug wasn't able to discover if X & Y was a real or integer so changed the params as per suggestion anyway and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Please view my update

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers.loadURL is deprecated. It is not neccessary to build GetFeatureInfo request manually, use WMSGetFeatureInfo control. I've wrote [post](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://gis-lab.info/qa/wmsgetfeatureinfo.html) about using WMSGEtFeatureInfo in OpenLayers. Try to modify your script accordingly this post.